# Библиотека проверки правописания

Tags: c++, windows, проверка-орфографии

Есть ли в с++ для windows библиотека проверки правописания (только правильности написания слова)?

Для Richedit я нашёл [EM_SETLANGOPTIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774250(v=vs.85).aspx), где включение spell-chek `IMF_SPELLCHECKING` доступно только с windows-8. Да и функции "проверь это слово" там нет.

В windows-xp у меня Firefox красным чёркает текст.

Если ли встроеная в OS проверка орфографии для winxp?

Если ли встроеная в OS проверка орфографии для win7?

Какие есть по-проще библиотеки проверки правописания? Интерисует функция "проверь это слово", но возможно есть и другие концепции. Подойдёт так же "надстройка" к Edit или Richedit.

Comment: Упомянутый Firefox использует файлы dic(словарь) и aff. Весом 2 Мб.

Comment: Можно попробовать GNU Aspell.

Comment: У aspell AFAIK нет официального порта под win, так что скорей всего придётся покорячится со сборкой... Из свободных решений я бы обратил внимание на *hunspell*, в частности она используется в хроме, OOo и огнелисе. Для русского, английского и многих других языков при этом используются словари от *myspell*.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Вы час назад дали (отредактировали) ответ, и требуете что бы я его принял?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите внимание на библиотеку [JamSpell](https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell). Написана изначально на С++. Для *JamSpell* есть в том числе обученные [орфографические модели](https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell-models) для трех языков - английский, французский, русский.

Пример использования:

```
#include <jamspell/spell_corrector.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

    NJamSpell::TSpellCorrector corrector;
    corrector.LoadLangModel("model.bin");

    corrector.FixFragment(L"I am the begt spell cherken!");
    // "I am the best spell checker!"

    corrector.GetCandidates({L"i", L"am", L"the", L"begt", L"spell", L"cherken"}, 3);
    // "best", "beat", "belt", "bet", "bent", ... )

    corrector.GetCandidates({L"i", L"am", L"the", L"begt", L"spell", L"cherken"}, 3);
    // "checker", "chicken", "checked", "wherein", "coherent", ... )
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, учтите, что обращаться в ответе к авторам других ответов безсмысленно, для этого существуют комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду иметь в виду!

Answer (score 3):

В Windows есть [встроенный API для проверки правописания](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/about-the-spell-checker-api), но он появился только в Windows 8. RichEdit именно его и использует.

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <exception>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <Spellcheck.h>

//кидает исключение, если HRESULT является ошибкой
inline void HR(HRESULT const result)
{
    if (S_OK != result) {
        wprintf(L"Error HRESULT 0x%x!!!\n", (UINT)result);
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

//выполняет проверку орфографии в тексте и возвращает число ошибок
int SpellCheck(LPCWSTR text) {
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISpellCheckerFactory> factory;

    HR(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SpellCheckerFactory), nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(factory),
        reinterpret_cast<void **>(factory.GetAddressOf())));

    BOOL supported = FALSE;

    HR(factory->IsSupported(L"ru-RU",
        &supported));

    if (supported == FALSE) {
        printf("Fatal error: Russian language not supported!\n");
        throw std::exception();
    }

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISpellChecker> checker;
    HR(factory->CreateSpellChecker(L"ru-RU",
        checker.GetAddressOf()));

    int n_errors = 0;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IEnumSpellingError> errors;
    HR(checker->Check(text,
        errors.GetAddressOf()));

    for (;;)
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISpellingError> error;

        if (S_OK != errors->Next(error.GetAddressOf()))
        {
            break;
        }       

        n_errors++;

        ULONG startIndex;
        HR(error->get_StartIndex(&startIndex));

        ULONG length;
        HR(error->get_Length(&length));

        std::wstring word(text + startIndex,
            text + startIndex + length);
        std::wcout << L"Ошибка в слове: " << word << std::endl;

        CORRECTIVE_ACTION action;
        HR(error->get_CorrectiveAction(&action));


        if (action == CORRECTIVE_ACTION_GET_SUGGESTIONS) {
            std::wcout << L" (Варианты исправления: ";
            Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IEnumString> suggestions;

            HR(checker->Suggest(word.c_str(),
                suggestions.GetAddressOf()));

            for (;;)
            {
                wchar_t * suggestion;

                if (S_OK != suggestions->Next(1, &suggestion, nullptr))
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Add the suggestion to a list for presentation
                std::wcout << suggestion << L" ";

                CoTaskMemFree(suggestion);
            }
            std::wcout << L")" << std::endl;
        }
        std::wcout  << std::endl;
    }

    return n_errors;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    HR(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));  

    auto text = L"Превед, медвед!";
    std::wcout << text << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"*********************************" << std::endl;

    auto res = SpellCheck(text);

    std::wcout << L"*********************************" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Всего ошибок: " << res<< std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*     Вывод программы:  

Превед, медвед!
*********************************
Ошибка в слове: Превед
 (Варианты исправления: Привод Провод Приведи Приведу Приведя Правде Привад Проведи Проведу Проведя )

Ошибка в слове: медвед
 (Варианты исправления: медведе медведи медведь медведю медведя медведей медведем медведка медведке медведки )

*********************************
Всего ошибок: 2
*/
```

**Источник:** [Using the C++ Spell Checking API](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/using-the-c-spell-checking-api.aspx)

В C++/CLI можно задействовать средства проверки правописания из WPF, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897845/240512).

Comment: Для 8-ки я нашёл... пока что на 7-ке сижу. Ничего, 7-ка вымрет через пару лет и всё будет ок))))) Тут пришла в голову мысль... а может эту dll можно выкачать, сделать ей regsvr32 чтото.dll и под 7 юзать?

Comment: @nick_n_a мало вытащить dll-ку, нужно еще понять, откуда она берет словари, и перенести их. Попробовать конечно можно, но вряд ли что-то выйдет, мне кажется. Ведь библиотека может использовать какие-то другие возможности ОС, которых не будет в старой версии.

Comment: Я хочу найти ответ для Win7. Ответ хороший, но пока что не подходит, хотя спустя какое-то время ответ станет актуальным.