# Распознавание текста с ошибками

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-данных, проверка-орфографии

Нужно кое-что реализовать. Допустим, пользователь ввёл текст: `"Пртвет"` или `"Првет"`, а скрипт распознал это слово, как `"Привет"` и выдал `True`. То есть, если он допустит ошибку в любом символе или пропустит один символ, то значение будет `True`.

Comment: И я [искал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829693/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) решение...

Comment: Очень нетривиальная задача со слишком широким спектром возможных решений...

Comment: у Вас c++, а у меня python

Comment: Может быть такое есть в регулярных выражениях?

Comment: А, ну да, тут посложнее задание. Вам нужно хотя бы частичный список правильных вариантов, и к нему формула для "генерации" полного списка правильных окончаний. Без этого - совсем никак.

Comment: При решении подобного класса задач ЯП не имеет решительно никакого значения) Вам следует сузить вопрос. Чего Вы хотите? Проверку по словарю? Нейронную сеть? Поддержку грамматики/морфологии? Не, вопрос интересный, но оффтоп, имхо.

Comment: А если слов мало, не сработает ли вариант ручного составления всех возможных вариантов и просто поиск по ним?

Comment: Есть массив со словами. Этот массив проверяется через условие if re.findall(massive, usertext, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Вариант ручного составления плохое решение. Т.к. вариантов может быть много с этими словами

Comment: @ANDROSHA, посмотрите еще этот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/752d0d171c88ab08a9745ae68e3d9b8c46f484d2/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/simple_distance.py

Comment: @gil9red случайно не знаете как установить pyxdameraulevenshtein на Windows? Выполняю команду: 'pip install pyxdameraulevenshtein' и появляется такая ошибка:
(первая строка)pyxdameraulevenshtein.c
(вторая)c:\users\androsha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: io.h: No such file or directory,
(третья)error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: @ANDROSHA, похоже какая-то проблема с компилятором visual studio, мб версия питона другая нужна, у меня 3.6 стоит, 64 битная. Я бы или заморочился с ее решением или использовал код из ссылки выше -- он не потребует компилирование. Вот посмотрите: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1ca24bd60d606b2f444e55a8f067aaed02bdb187/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/match_two_words.py

Comment: @gil9red ещё такой вопрос, а можно ли добавить к этому алгоритму регулярные выражения? Если я сделаю, к примеру if re.findall(fix_command(usertext, words), usertext): print('ok'), то выйдет то же самое, что и без этого алгоритма, т.к. он вернёт опять это же слово без ошибок, которое написал пользователь с ошибками и print не сработает. А если пользователь введёт слово без ошибок, то print сработает

Comment: @ANDROSHA, тогда лучше так: `if fix_command(usertext, words) == usertext: print('ok')`

Comment: @gil9red а если пользователь введёт символы по несколько раз, допустим `приветттт`, то условие уже не сработает)
Нужно как-то добавить квантификаторы `*?` к некоторым символам и шаблоны с квантификаторами в конец и начало строки: `\s?\S?`

Comment: @ANDROSHA А фиг его знает, тут нужно подумать ) задайте отдельный вопрос с этой проблемой, т.к. тут уже вопрос по регуляркам

Comment: @gil9red до 4 часов утра пытался сделать поддержку регулярных выражений и чёт не получалось) ладно, задам вопрос тогда

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть такой алгоритм [Расстояние Дамерау — Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83_%E2%80%94_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), он позволит найти разницу между двумя последовательностями и его можно использоваться для исправления опечаток.

Код ниже [был взят и адаптирован](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f8def2eb7dfcf82e3ebca246871e08a2c85cd380/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/use__pyxdameraulevenshtein/fix_command.py) из функции, используемой в боте для проверки введенных пользователем команд:

```
# pip install pyxDamerauLevenshtein
# https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein
# SOURCE: https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein/blob/master/examples/examples.py


def fix_command(text, words=['Привет']):
    import numpy as np
    array = np.array(words)

    from pyxdameraulevenshtein import normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance_ndarray
    result = list(zip(words, list(normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance_ndarray(text, array))))

    command, rate = min(result, key=lambda x: x[1])

    # Подобранное значение для определения совпадения текста среди значений указанного списка
    # Если True, считаем что слишком много ошибок в слове, т.е. text среди all_commands нет
    if rate > 0.40:
        return

    return command


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fix_command('Привет'))  # Привет
    print(fix_command('Првет'))   # Привет
    print(fix_command('Прывет'))  # Привет
    print(fix_command('Привед'))  # Привет
    print(fix_command('Превед'))  # Привет
```

C значением в `if rate > 0.40:` можно поиграться, настраивая "вредность" алгоритма -- чем значение `rate` больше, тем большая разница между последовательностями будет принята, но тем выше шанс получить неожиданный результат.

---

Если нужно сравнить одну строку с другой, можно взять этот [пример модуля](https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein#using-this-code):

```
from pyxdameraulevenshtein import damerau_levenshtein_distance, normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance
damerau_levenshtein_distance('smtih', 'smith')  # expected result: 1
normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance('smtih', 'smith')  # expected result: 0.2
damerau_levenshtein_distance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 7, 10, 11, 4])  # expected result: 7
```

Функция `damerau_levenshtein_distance` вернет разницу в символах между строками.

[Сделал небольшой пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/bb6846b6d231d80059444ec5c4fe7c49c22e64e8/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/use__pyxdameraulevenshtein/match_two_words.py) использования:

```
# pip install pyxDamerauLevenshtein
# SOURCE: https://github.com/gfairchild/pyxDamerauLevenshtein


def match_two_words(word_1, word_2):
    from pyxdameraulevenshtein import damerau_levenshtein_distance
    number = damerau_levenshtein_distance(word_1, word_2)

    # Считаем что разница в 2 символа и меньше еще нормальная
    return number < 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    need_word = 'Привет'

    print(match_two_words('Привет', need_word))  # True
    print(match_two_words('Првет', need_word))   # True
    print(match_two_words('Прывет', need_word))  # True
    print(match_two_words('Привед', need_word))  # True
    print(match_two_words('Превед', need_word))  # True

    print(match_two_words('Преед', need_word))   # False
```

Comment: Советую обратить внимание на [модуль `jellyfish`](http://jellyfish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), который объединил в себе 6 подобных алгоритмов...

Comment: @MaxU, я посмотрю, эта тема интересная :)

Comment: Решение, огонь! Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Прочитайте [теорию](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8,_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) и [реализацию](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) нахождения расстояния Левенштейна (на Python там есть). Если кратко, то расстояние Левенштейна - это минимальное количество символов, которое нужно добавить/удалить/изменить в одном слове, чтобы получить другое. Можете вычислять это расстояние между введенным словом и словами из массива, находить наименьшее и, если оно меньше или равно необходимой вам константе, считать, что слово введено верно.

Вот простой пример реализации на Python (см. ссылку выше)

```
def distance(a, b):
    "Calculates the Levenshtein distance between a and b."
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        # Make sure n <= m, to use O(min(n,m)) space
        a, b = b, a
        n, m = m, n

    current_row = range(n+1) # Keep current and previous row, not entire matrix
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i]+[0]*n
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            add, delete, change = previous_row[j]+1, current_row[j-1]+1, previous_row[j-1]
            if a[j-1] != b[i-1]:
                change += 1
            current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

    return current_row[n]
```

Comment: Мб добавить в ваш ответ пример с кодом? По второй ссылке есть пример на питоне (он клевый и простой, поэтому добавил его к себе), можете им воспользоваться, чтобы у вас ответе был пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/752d0d171c88ab08a9745ae68e3d9b8c46f484d2/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/simple_distance.py

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Кстати, вы, наверно, заметили, но я на всякий случай уточню, что там именно _Расстояние Левенштейна_, а не _Расстояние Дамерау — Левенштейна_ как у вас в ответе (т.е. без учета возможности переставить символы).